# How to store single entity instead of collection?

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to create an entity which should store history of my employee. Here is my table

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee_history (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    employee_id INT,
    company_id INT,
    hire_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    resign_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (id)
);
```

The problem is I need to store only one entity `EmployeeHistory`, not `Collection<EmployeeHistory>`. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

UPD:

Result for employee Mike:

```
1, Mike,  GridDynamics,  2000-08-10,  2003-01-01
2, Mike,  IBM,           2012-04-03,  2014-02-15
3, Mike,  GridDynamics,  1997-04-17,  1998-03-08
```

UPD2:

My `Company` entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonProperty("employees")
    private List<Employee> employees;
```

And `Employee` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    Integer id;

    @Column
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonProperty("company")
    private Company company;
```

Comment: What is wrong with a `OneToOne` mapping?

Comment: So you seem need a one-to-one mapping in EmployeeHistory to Employee and to Company. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: The issue is to store `EmployeeHistory` with collection of `Record` inside. I need to assemble complex object which consist result of joins.

Comment: Can you provide your entity classes? Using a @OneToOne mapping between Employee and Company does exactly what you're asking for. Based off of your reply, the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have many history records related to an employee.

you can create a table called `EMPLOYEE` and another table called `EMPLOYEE_HISTORY`

now to store employee history, suppose there are 5 records for one employee.

you can create an entry in `EMPLOYEE` with employee details

you can have `FK_EMPLOYEE` in `EMPLOYEE_HISTORY` which will map all records in history table to unique employee entry in `EMPLOYEE` table and thus you can have all 5 history records associated to an employee.

Comment: so for that you need to create another table called employee_history and create all history transactions. make sure those are associated with the employee entry you did in EMPLOYEE table. only one entity is not enough to store such relational data.

Comment: so iterate over the collection and do all entries in history table. what is the problem then?

Comment: I need only a single entity not collection. This is the essence of the problem.

Comment: from your code you edited, i can see that there is no unique identifier using which you can associate the history record to employee, there has to be one like `id`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51179/discussion-between-vd-and-arkasha)